# Comparing areas of two raster files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, hydrology, watershed, catchment-area

I need to compare the areas of two rasters for calculating the percentage parts from another.
For example, I have one raster file which shows separated agriculture fields. The value of each field is 1 and the space between the fields is noDATA. In the second raster all fields from the first raster are divided in catchment areas and the value of each catchment area represents the size of the area. Now I want to calculate what percentage have the single catchment areas of the whole field.  I`m using ArcMap and each pixel represents 1 qm.

Raster 1 is showing the fields
[image: Raster 1 is showing the fields]

Raster 2 is showing the catchment Area
[image: Raster 2 is showing the catchment Area]

One upon the other
[image: Both raster upon the other]

Comment: Tabulate area tool can do it

Comment: When i try to run tabulate area i get an error "Unable to allocate memory"  or arcmap is completely crashing. I  also tried solutions for the error but its not working.

Comment: I generally find that kind of processing easier with vectors. You may want to convert the raster to polygons first.

Comment: I got it, a geodatabase brought the solution to my errors. Now its working. Thanks for your hint. :)